# How to make piechart with YSLD in Geoserver style

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, chart, ysld

It is possible to make piechart style in Geoserver WMS using XML SLD. For this adding chart extension is required.

Now, is it possible to make such piechart with YSLD ?

---

Additional info:

My colleague tried it with YSLD with the following result:
[image]

The `size: ${diameter}` seems to be understood correctly by GeoServer as the size of grey squares vary.

Now to the problem: the piechart is rendered only as grey square as if the piechart plugin is not installed. Meanwhile I confirm that the piechart plugin is in place and other SLD style (not YSLD) specifying piecharts are rendered as expected.

How to fix this?

My playground:

- GeoServer 2.14.3 (with chart extension)
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.32 Server
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit on Xeon E5-1660 3GHz, 32GB memory
- PostgreSQL 9.6.11, PostGIS 2.5